# move forward and backward by one word

Tags: gnome-terminal

In a GNOME terminal, the standard ways of **moving forward or backward** by **one word** do not work.

In spite of what the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Change_the_text) says:

> **alt+b** : Goes back one word at a time.
>
> **alt+f** : Moves forward one word at a time.

If I do the above, I just open the **drop-down menu** for Tabs and Edit.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the Terminal, go to **Edit** → **Keyboard Shortcuts...** and untick the **Enable menu access keys** box.

Answer (score 39):

just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd>

Comment: Uh! I totally prefer this!

Comment: And I'm so psyched that this command seems to work *everywhere*: on a terminal, on gedit, on this very text box too!! :-o

Comment: @RickyRobinson: This little feature is one of the top 5 reasons I prefer Linux over every other OS :)

Comment: Doesn't it work on a mac?

Comment: @RickyRobinson it does, just hold option instead of ctrl, it even works in windows with ctrl... this is by no means a hidden feature, it's LITERALLY used everywhere

Comment: It's even available on Windows

Comment: This just deletes a word for me

Comment: NOTE: It will not work if you have an .inputrc on your home directory which does not include /etc/inputrc. The reason it works is because they are set such in /etc/inputrc.

Answer (score 8):

From the [readline manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man3/readline.3readline.html) (readline is the library that implements these commands):

> An emacs-style notation is used to denote keystrokes.  Control keys denoted  by C-key, e.g., C-n means Control-N.  Similarly, meta keys are denoted by M-key, so M-x means Meta-X.  (**On keyboards  without a meta key,  M-x means ESC x, i.e., press the Escape key then the x key.**  This makes ESC the meta prefix.  The combination M-C-x means  ESC-Control-x, or  press the Escape key then hold the Control key while pressing the x key.)

@Galgalesh is correct that you use the Ctrl+arrow keys to jump words in Ubuntu.  In many (most?) other distributions the key combo is Alt+arrows.

In order to use Alt+f/Alt+b without interfering with the menus, use <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>f</kbd> (press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, THEN press <kbd>f</kbd>, not both at the same time).

The reason I mention this is that you can use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>(key)</kbd> trick for *other* commands, too.  E.g., if you've started editing a previous command and decide you want to revert it, use <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>.